# How to validate rebuilt svn repository

Tags: svn, repository

I rebuilt a huge svn repository (over 350GB - took more than 11 days to complete).
How can I validate the new repo against the existing one.
I tried "svn ls" on both and they are same - but that just dumps the root directory. 
Are there any better ways of doing it or I just have to do random tests?
fyi, repository has more than 600K revisions and 16K+ folders in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare the repositories on a file level instead from the svn client side...cause if you have created them via dump/load cycle they have to be identical except the new revisions added during the load cycle... so i would suggest to do a diff between the two repository trees...via unix diff tool if you are on unix...but 350 GB compare will take it's time but that the costs you have to pay...

```
diff -r Repos1 Repos2
```

Should be an empty result except for the new revsions...

Or you can do a a second svnadmin dump Repos2 >repos2.dump and compare it with the one you used to created this. The result should be identically ...(except for the new revisions)...

Or write a script checkout a number (or all?) of the revsions from both repositories and make a comparsion on that level....but i assume this will take more time...

Answer (score 1):

You could dump the log of each repo to a file, and diff the log files.

Answer (score 1):

svn ls -R dumps every folder, not only the root directory. But it does not guarantee the shown content is really valid.

One thing you should do is check out everything from both repositories to two clean directories and run a recursive compare on both directory trees (excluding the .svn subfolders, of course). If you need some advice for the the last step, tell us which OS you are working with.

This does not check the version history, of course, but guarantees at least there is not anything from the head revision missing.

To make some selective checks for the version history, check out some older revisions (for example, some tagged revisions), and compare them the same way as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar to verify a svn repository against its svnadmin sync clone-copy repository.  For each revision number $r = 1 (or 0) to HEAD (svnlook youngest), I did the following:

```
svnadmin dump -q --incremental --deltas -r $r /path/to/repo1 > source.txt
svnadmin dump -q --incremental --deltas -r $r /path/to/repo2 > target.txt
diff --text --ignore-matching-lines='^\(UUID: [0-9a-f-]\+\|Prop-delta: true\|Prop-content-length: [0-9]\+\|Content-length: [0-9]\+\|PROPS-END\|\s*\)$' source.txt target.txt
```

Note: if source.txt is bigger than 1GB, I skip the diff with a warning otherwise diff takes too much ram.  Someday, maybe I will split the diff input into chunks for large dumps.  I also had to add --deltas or I ended up with some false differences for property information.

I think this is working like I want and giving me some confidence (based on svnadmin dump) that svnadmin sync is working correctly.

Regards,

- Mark